# Value of π*φ and π/φ

Tags: integration, pi, golden-ratio

I found the expression of $\pi\varphi$ and $\pi/\varphi$ on Twitter via @AnecdotesMaths (https://twitter.com/AnecdotesMaths/status/1241032301783461890) in terms of an integral, and I wondered if anyone knew a proof for this ?
Have a nice day !

$$\pi\times\varphi=\int_0^\infty\frac{5}{1+x^{10}} dx.$$
$$\frac{\pi}{\varphi}=\int_0^\infty\frac{5x^2}{1+x^{10}} dx.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.